# how to get id from url in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]

Hello! I just want to get an Id through a current page URL in lightning component...

How to get this id from the component side?

should this work on `Aapexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use this interface: force:hasRecordId

```
 <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<b>This is recordID {!v.recordId} </b><br/>
</aura:componet>
```

javascript:

```
 doInit:function(componet,event,helper){
   component.get("v.recordId");
  }
```

***Notes:***

- If component implements force:hasRecordId interface, you no need to add
  a recordId attribute to the component.
- The component’s controller can access the ID of the current record
  from the recordId attribute, using component.get("v.recordId"). The
  recordId attribute is automatically added to the component by the
  force:hasRecordId interface.

Read this Link for more Information:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation