# Passing ID to component

Tags: lightning-apps

I have a custom objet related to the account.  I want to launch that component from the button or action from the account.

The purpose of the component is to take an account ID and present all of the related records for this account.  The component has filters so that the results can be filtered.  It also has a related object on the component and displays these related records.

I’m struggling to figure out if this can be done and if so, how.

Thank you!!!

Fred

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this component and do you expect to receive account Id or custom Object Id? Please edit your question to provide more clarity

Comment: Thanks Anmol. I added more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please create a Lightning component with quick action
2. After clicking the button Get the "recordId" form URL  in JS method and pass to server (Apex Controller) and display related records based on that Id

**Refer Below stack exchange Posts:**

[how to get id from url in lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237351/how-to-get-id-from-url-in-lightning-component)

**Calling server side from js side:**

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_server

3. Write onchange function on Filters.whenever filter changes write dynamic soql query to get the records.

If you  still need any information.I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer you seek is at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation
Your component markup needs to contain

```
implements="force:hasRecordId"
```

which is automatically created if you create a new Lightning Component in the Developer Console and select "Lightning Record Page".

In your component markup you need to declare a recordId attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
```

From the controller you can access that with

```
var accountId = component.get("v.recordId");
```

So when your Lightning component is called from an Account record, recordId is automatically filled with the Accounts Id.

Comment: Thank you both.  It sounds like the id is just there as from the calling record.  That is what I was missing as I could not understand how the component would "get" the id.  I will run with this.  Thank you both!!!!